# How do I revert my github branch to develop?

Tags: github, gitkraken

my main branch gives problems but my develop branch is working just fine. how can i set my main branch back to develop? i've tried reset and rebase and everything
[image: image of my GitKraken]

Comment: Do this. git reset —hard. Then git checkout develop from cmd

Answer (score 1):

You may hard reset your branch to `develop`:

```
# from your feature branch
git reset --hard develop
```

Note that you may need to force push this branch to the remote:

```
git push --force origin feature
```